# Laravel (5.4) passport routes with current user that also works if not logged in

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-passport

I'm trying to make one route in laravel which can have a user if it is logged-in but can still work if not.

In my case I have a table called "venues" and a "user" that can have a venue as his favourite.

So these are my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'bindings', 'auth:api']], function () {
    Route::match(['GET', 'OPTIONS'], 'venue/{venue}', 'VenuesController@getVenue')->name('venue')->where('venue', '[0-9]+');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'bindings', 'api'], 'namespace' => 'Api'], function () {
    Route::match(['GET', 'OPTIONS'], 'venue/{venue}', 'VenuesController@getVenue')->name('venue')->where('venue', '[0-9]+');
});
```

Now I noticed that `Auth::user();` is only available in the route with the middleware with `'auth:api'` but I also want it to get the venue if the user is not logged in. And using both groups doesn't work this way.

My Venue model looks like this:

```
class Venue extends Model
{
    protected $appends = [
        'favourite',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'venue_user');
    }

    public function getFavouriteAttribute()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $isFav = false;
        if ($user) {
            if ($user->venues) {
                foreach ($user->venues as $item) {
                    if ($item->id === $this->id) {
                        $isFav = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $isFav;
    }
}
```

There must be a better way to do this.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer to my own question.
Apparently the right way to get the current of Passport is by doing:

```
$user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
```

`Auth::user()` is only available in routes with a middlewhere of `'auth:api'` but this one is available everywhere if I say so correctly.

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong :)